# This may be very easy, but i new to PHP. I want to change Array Index

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, key

I want to change Array Index.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 456
    [2] => 789
    [3] => 258
)
```

I want to change this from somtheing like array:

```
Array(
                                [0] => Array
                                          (
                                            [un] => 123
                                          )
                                [1] => Array
                                          (
                                            [un] => 456
                                          )
                                [2] => Array
                                          (
                                            [un] => 789
                                          )
                                [3] => Array
                                          (
                                            [un] => 258
                                          )
                          )
```

I have tried with several way to convert it, I used array_key, also tried with foreach loop.

Can anyone please guide me to get the output?

I have tried a loop:

```
$newArray = [];
                        
                        for($i=0 ; $i < count($oldArray) ; $i++)
                        {
                          $newArray['un'] = $oldArray;
                        }
                      print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: Show what you have tried, even if it didn't work. We need to see what you've attempted, as that's usually a good starting point for us to assist with debugging. Plus, it's expected that you make an effort to solve your own issue, as Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call this array $old

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 123
        [1] => 456
        [2] => 789
        [3] => 258
    )
```

To wrap that array, into another array, we will create a new array, called $new

```
$new = array();
```

To actually accomplish this, here is how:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($old); $x++) {
    $new[]= array("un" => $old[$x]);
}
```

By adding [] to the end of $new, we will be appending each value ($old[$x]) to an index in $new, which will create your desired outcome. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your message, I have tried this. But i got same output.

Comment: VDR, my apologies, I missed a step :) wrapping $old[$x] with an array and associated the key "un" will solve it using =>, I just edited the answer. Hope this helps!